# How to indicate failed authentication reason to flex client with JAAS?

Tags: java, apache-flex, jboss, blazeds, jaas

We're using :

- JBoss 5
- Flex SDK 3.5
- BlazeDS 3, with integrated authentication (through JAAS and JBossSX)

Failed login are always indicated to the flex client by the same fault code : *Client.Authentication*

However, the underlying JAAS *LoginModule* throws a specific *javax.security.auth.login.LoginException* subclass.

How can we propagate the failed login reason to the flex client ?

Answer (score 0):

BlazeDS knows how to serialize your Throwable object. You can throw a custom exception from Java, add a fault handler to your remote object in Flex and you can recover your exception from the FaultEvent event.